# EWS Java SendInvitationsMode SendToNone

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, appointment

i dont understand a sence of `SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone`.

Msdn.microsoft.com shows, how appointment could be created with this 
option:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx

But when i am not using this option and set only start- and end-date to the same date (for example 2016-12-12) and save like this:

```
appointment.save();
```

, i expect, that outlook shows me in my calender this appointment only on the date: 2016-12-12.
But outlook shows me some different days. Obviously start- and end-date will be ignored, when i'am not set this option, when i save appointment: `SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone`.

"SendToNone" means for me, that this appointment will not be send to something else.

Answer (score 0):

SendToNone means if you have a Meeting that when you create the meeting appointment meeting invitations will not be sent when you call save.

> But when i am not using this option and set only start- and end-date to the same date (for example 2016-12-12) and save like this:

What are you trying to achieve though? are you trying to create an All Day appointment ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn756538(v=exchg.150).aspx the thing to be careful of here is matching the timezone if you have users in different timezone.

Comment: yes, i would like achieve to send all-day-appointment.
Normaly all-day-appointment appears on top from calender-view in outlook.
In your link you can see property: `allDayEvent.IsAllDayEvent = true;`. I´ve set this property too and i set my timezone. But it does not work. My all-day appointment appears at 1 am instead of top from outlook-kalender.
Only when i´ve set this option and i saved appointment, it appears on top from calender. It seems that this option "SendToNone" has something to do with appointment-position within calender-view by outlook.